# Azure Standard Logic app creation using Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, azure-logic-app-standard

I am trying to create/deploy Azure Standard Logic App using Terrform and getting below error message.

```
Error: creating Logic App Standard: (Site Name "shd-sbx-spikeecrime-sla" / Resource Group "shd-sbx-uks-spikeecrime-rg"): web.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> <nil>
```

Terraform configs:

```
resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "main" {
  name                = "${local.business_unit}-${local.environment}-${local.identifier}-asp"
  location            = module.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name = module.resource_group.name
  kind                = "elastic"


  sku {
    tier = "WorkflowStandard"
    size = "WS1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "main" {
  name                     = "${local.business_unit}0${local.environment}0${local.identifier}0sa"
  location                 = module.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name      = module.resource_group.name
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}


resource "azurerm_logic_app_standard" "main" {
  name                       = "${local.business_unit}-${local.environment}-${local.identifier}-sla"
  location                   = module.resource_group.location
  resource_group_name        = module.resource_group.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.main.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.main.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.main.primary_access_key

  app_settings = {
    FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME     = "node"
    WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION = "~18"
  }
}
```

TF plan output:

```
terraform apply --auto-approve
module.resource_group.azurerm_resource_group.main: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/ad0af8a3-80b9-4d65-a992-339cf04886f1/resourceGroups/shd-sbx-uks-spikeecrime-rg]
azurerm_app_service_plan.main: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/ad0af8a3-80b9-4d65-a992-339cf04886f1/resourceGroups/shd-sbx-uks-spikeecrime-rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/shd-sbx-spikeecrime-asp]
azurerm_storage_account.main: Refreshing state... [id=/subscriptions/ad0af8a3-80b9-4d65-a992-339cf04886f1/resourceGroups/shd-sbx-uks-spikeecrime-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/shd0sbx0spikeecrime0sa]

Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform

Terraform detected the following changes made outside of Terraform since the last "terraform apply":

  # azurerm_storage_account.main has changed
  ~ resource "azurerm_storage_account" "main" {
        id                                = "/subscriptions/ad0af8a3-80b9-4d65-a992-339cf04886f1/resourceGroups/shd-sbx-uks-spikeecrime-rg/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/shd0sbx0spikeecrime0sa"
        name                              = "shd0sbx0spikeecrime0sa"
      + tags                              = {}
        # (37 unchanged attributes hidden)




        # (4 unchanged blocks hidden)
    }


Unless you have made equivalent changes to your configuration, or ignored the relevant attributes using ignore_changes, the following plan may include actions to undo or respond to these changes.

──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────

Terraform used the selected providers to generate the following execution plan. Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  + create

Terraform will perform the following actions:

  # azurerm_logic_app_standard.main will be created
  + resource "azurerm_logic_app_standard" "main" {
      + app_service_plan_id            = "/subscriptions/ad0af8a3-80b9-4d65-a992-339cf04886f1/resourceGroups/shd-sbx-uks-spikeecrime-rg/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/shd-sbx-spikeecrime-asp"
      + app_settings                   = {
          + "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME"     = "node"
          + "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" = "~18"
        }
      + bundle_version                 = "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
      + client_affinity_enabled        = (known after apply)
      + custom_domain_verification_id  = (known after apply)
      + default_hostname               = (known after apply)
      + enabled                        = true
      + https_only                     = false
      + id                             = (known after apply)
      + kind                           = (known after apply)
      + location                       = "uksouth"
      + name                           = "shd-sbx-spikeecrime-sla"
      + outbound_ip_addresses          = (known after apply)
      + possible_outbound_ip_addresses = (known after apply)
      + resource_group_name            = "shd-sbx-uks-spikeecrime-rg"
      + site_credential                = (known after apply)
      + storage_account_access_key     = (sensitive value)
      + storage_account_name           = "shd0sbx0spikeecrime0sa"
      + storage_account_share_name     = (known after apply)
      + use_extension_bundle           = true
      + version                        = "~3"

      + connection_string {
          + name  = (known after apply)
          + type  = (known after apply)
          + value = (sensitive value)
        }

      + site_config {
          + always_on                        = (known after apply)
          + app_scale_limit                  = (known after apply)
          + auto_swap_slot_name              = (known after apply)
          + dotnet_framework_version         = (known after apply)
          + elastic_instance_minimum         = (known after apply)
          + ftps_state                       = (known after apply)
          + health_check_path                = (known after apply)
          + http2_enabled                    = (known after apply)
          + ip_restriction                   = (known after apply)
          + linux_fx_version                 = (known after apply)
          + min_tls_version                  = (known after apply)
          + pre_warmed_instance_count        = (known after apply)
          + public_network_access_enabled    = (known after apply)
          + runtime_scale_monitoring_enabled = (known after apply)
          + scm_ip_restriction               = (known after apply)
          + scm_min_tls_version              = (known after apply)
          + scm_type                         = (known after apply)
          + scm_use_main_ip_restriction      = (known after apply)
          + use_32_bit_worker_process        = (known after apply)
          + vnet_route_all_enabled           = (known after apply)
          + websockets_enabled               = (known after apply)

          + cors {
              + allowed_origins     = (known after apply)
              + support_credentials = (known after apply)
            }
        }
    }

Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
azurerm_logic_app_standard.main: Creating...
azurerm_logic_app_standard.main: Still creating... [10s elapsed]
╷
│ Warning: Deprecated Resource
│ 
│   with azurerm_app_service_plan.main,
│   on standard_logic_app.tf line 2, in resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "main":
│    2: resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "main" {
│ 
│ The `azurerm_app_service_plan` resource has been superseded by the `azurerm_service_plan` resource. Whilst this resource will continue to be available in the 2.x and 3.x releases it is
│ feature-frozen for compatibility purposes, will no longer receive any updates and will be removed in a future major release of the Azure Provider.
│ 
│ (and one more similar warning elsewhere)
╵
╷
│ Error: creating Logic App Standard: (Site Name "shd-sbx-spikeecrime-sla" / Resource Group "shd-sbx-uks-spikeecrime-rg"): web.AppsClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=<nil> <nil>
│ 
│   with azurerm_logic_app_standard.main,
│   on standard_logic_app.tf line 24, in resource "azurerm_logic_app_standard" "main":
│   24: resource "azurerm_logic_app_standard" "main" {
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very transient issue which is not related to the `azurerm` side.

***Need to check below:***

- Make sure that you have logged in with the correct azure login credentials and has necessary permissions to create or update the resource.
- Try upgrading the terraform and CLI version using `terraform init -upgrade`. If still the issue persists, run the same code in `VS code` to avoid conflicts.
- Instead of using modules for resource group delegation, try using `resource` or `data` block as shown below.
- Provide `--debug` argument along with the `terraform apply` to retrieve more information on the error part.
- Moreover, check the configuration and property values of app service plan, storage account tier details are given accurately with the help of terraform registry [`azurerm_logic_app_standard`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/logic_app_standard) document.

*I tried below terraform code in my environment and was able to deploy it successfully as shown below.*

```bash
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "xxxx"
}

data "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "newjstorage"
  resource_group_name      = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "newjplans"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  kind                = "elastic"


  sku {
    tier = "WorkflowStandard"
    size = "WS1"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_logic_app_standard" "example" {
  name                       = "newtodayapp"
  location                   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = data.azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = data.azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key

  app_settings = {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME"     = "node"
    "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION" = "~18"
  }
}
```

***Deployment succeeded:***

[image]

[image]